# Simple Android translation app not working

Tags: android

I made a simple Java CLI program for an assignment, and now I'm trying to make it into an Android app for fun/experience. 
However, it's not working... It's a translation app, and when I put in a word that I know is in the dictionary it still gives me my message I put in for if the user puts in an invalid word. 
I believe what's happening is it's not ever reading in the dictionary file properly, as Eclipse's LogCat is giving me the following message on runtime: " Can't open file for reading."

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TreeMap<String, String> tree = new TreeMap<String, String>();
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Scanner dictinput = null;
 try{
     getAssets().open("dict.txt");
    dictinput = new Scanner(getAssets().open("dict.txt"));
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Could not open file");
        System.exit(-1);            

 }//Puts the dictionary in a stringbuffer
 StringBuffer dict = new StringBuffer();
 String[] arrtemp = new String[1600];
 while(dictinput.hasNext()) {
     dict.append(dictinput.nextLine());
     dict.append("|");

 }//Then puts it in a string so it can be split at the |'s using .split
 String strstr = dict.toString();
 arrtemp = strstr.split("\\|");

 //puts the dictionary into a treemap
 for(int i=0; i<arrtemp.length-1; i++) {
     if(i==0)
         tree.put(arrtemp[i].toLowerCase(), arrtemp[i+1]);
     else {
         i++;
         tree.put(arrtemp[i].toLowerCase(), arrtemp[i+1]);
     }

 }
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editmessage);//The only way I've         found to get the text from the user.
    String temp = editText.toString();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(temp);
    String finalmessage = null;
    while(scan.hasNext()){

     String temp1 = scan.next();
     if (tree.containsKey(temp1.toLowerCase()))
        finalmessage = temp;
     else
         finalmessage = "No match found, try another word or phrase";
 }



    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, finalmessage);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your textfile located? I would imagine the problem might be it is not saved under /res/raw in your project folder, after which you can use an inputstream like:

```
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.textfilename);
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while(blah){
           do stuff
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        handle errors
    }
```

Comment: Why would you put a text file in `/res/drawable`?

Comment: Fine, keep it in either raw or assets. This was just a quick fix to give the idea of it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Hmm, ok can I still use a Scanner with that? It needs to be a scanner for the rest of my program to work. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Check out java.io.inputStreamReader, you can assign a scanner as
    Scanner sc =  new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new InputStream(_input your inputstream here))